# codeigniter image upload cant grab file name

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

i have try and try and i just cant get my image to upload.
And i cant grab my image name when i try to echo it out :S.

can you see what im doing wrong.

here is my controller:

```
<?php 
//ADMIN PAGE
if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

class News extends CI_Controller {


    //Write post when logged in as admin
    function write()
    {

        //insert image
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH .'/archive/img/news/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = '9000';
        $config['encrypt_name']     = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('newsImage');

        $file_data = $this->upload->data();

        $newsData = array(
            'headline'      => $this->input->post('headline'),
            'description'   => $this->input->post('description'),
            'content'       => $this->input->post('content'),
            'creater'       => $this->session->userdata('username'),
            'ip'            => $this->session->userdata('ip'),
            'imgPath'       => $file_data['file_name']
        );


        echo "<pre>";
        //print_r( $this->upload->data());
        //print_r($file_data);
        //print_r($_FILES);
        //print_r($this->input->post());
        print_r($newsData);
        echo "</pre>";


        $this->load->model('admin/news_model');
        $this->news_model->insertNews($newsData);


        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/write_view';
        $this->load->view('template', $data);

    }

}
```

And my view file where i upload my image

```
<div id="inputStyle">


<?php

echo form_open_multipart('admin/news/write');

echo form_input('headline', 'overskrift');

echo form_upload('newsImage');

echo form_textarea('description', 'indhold');

echo form_textarea('content', 'content');

echo form_submit('create', 'Opret nyhed');

echo form_close();


?>




</div><!-- inputStyle -->
```

Comment: check if there was any error with `$this->upload->display_errors()` before you try to grab the filename

Comment: @Kokers i got this error: The upload path does not appear to be valid. how do i get the full path? my folder is not in the application folder but in the root folder

Comment: make sure the destination folder is writable (775 or 777)

Comment: remove APPPATH from `config['upload_path']..`. If I understood you right, this should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have edited your code. It may be work for you. If your folder is in root folder of application then no need to use APPPATH. I have also edited this in your code. Try this.

```
//Write post when logged in as admin
function write()
{
    //insert image
    $config['upload_path'] = 'archive/img/news/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = '9000';
    $config['encrypt_name']     = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('newsImage');

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

    $newsData = array(
        'headline'      => $this->input->post('headline'),
        'description'   => $this->input->post('description'),
        'content'       => $this->input->post('content'),
        'creater'       => $this->session->userdata('username'),
        'ip'            => $this->session->userdata('ip'),
        'imgPath'       => $_FILES['newsImage']['name']
    );


    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r( $this->upload->data());
    //print_r($file_data);
    //print_r($_FILES);
    //print_r($this->input->post());
    print_r($newsData);
    echo "</pre>";


    $this->load->model('admin/news_model');
    $this->news_model->insertNews($newsData);


    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/write_view';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Comment: Damn thanks :), but if i want to grab the encrypted name how do i do that?

Comment: I don't know why you want to grab encrypted name?

Comment: because i want to store the name in the database so i can show to right news image to my news post :)

Comment: you can store real name of image in database.

Comment: but on my folder the image name is the crypted name :(

Comment: but i want the image to be encrypt so i dont upload 2 image with the same name :)

Comment: for that you can use real name attached with current timestamp. like this. 1324995306_indiatravel.jpg