# File name not grabbed when using CodeIgniter upload library

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

Firstly can I request this is NOT marked as duplicate. I have read the other posts on SO regarding issues with the CodeIgniter upload library and sadly they do not cover this. I have also extensively read the CI documentation and everything suggests this should work correctly.

I am using a very simple form to grab the file, which is uploaded correctly to the images folder. The full_path of the file is also written successfully to a db table called images. The filename however is blank.

My form:

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('image_upload/do_upload');?>

    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" multiple="true" />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

    </form>
```

My Controller function:

```
    function do_upload()
     {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'c:/wamp/www/honest/images';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($image_data); echo '</pre>';

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = 'imageupload';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            echo "FAILED";
        }
         else
        {
          $data = array(
            'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
            'fullpath' => $image_data['full_path']
          );
          $this->db->insert('images', $data);   
          $this->load->view('imageupload');
        }
    }
```

I am using

```
    echo print_r($image_data); echo;
```

To display the associated image data but this is all that is returned:

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => 
    [file_type] => 
    [file_path] => c:/wamp/www/honest/images/
    [full_path] => c:/wamp/www/honest/images/
    [raw_name] => 
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 
    [file_ext] => 
    [file_size] => 
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

I can't work out why it is not grabbing the file name and other details - can someone help spot what is hopefully a simple error?

Many thanks,

DP.

Comment: you question seem like similar with this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643806/codeigniter-image-upload-cant-grab-file-name?rq=1

Comment: Yup - read that one, didn't work. But another poster has just spotted the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting your uploaded data *before* you actually upload anything. That's why your `$image_data` only contains your configuration values. Move your `$image_data = $this->upload->data();` call to after actually performing the `do_upload()` (into your else block):

```
     function do_upload()
     {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'c:/wamp/www/honest/images';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = 'imageupload';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            echo "FAILED";
        }
         else
        {
          $image_data = $this->upload->data();
          $data = array(
            'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
            'fullpath' => $image_data['full_path']
          );
          $this->db->insert('images', $data);   
          $this->load->view('imageupload');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! - thanks loads Wolf. This has baffled me all day. I imagined that the $this->load->library('upload', $config);  had already performed the upload - apparently not!

Comment: @DavidPride You're welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as correct.